# Let $\bf{A}$ be a $n\times n$ matrix, $\bf{b}$ and $\bf{x}$ be $p-$vector. Compute $\frac{\partial^2Q(\bf{x})}{\partial\bf{x}\partial\bf{x^T}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative

> Let $\bf{A}$ be a $n\times n$ matrix, $\bf{b}$ be $p-$vector, and $\bf{x}$ be $p-$vector. Compute $$\frac{\partial^2Q(\bf{x})}{\partial\bf{x}\partial\bf{x^T}}$$ where $Q\bf{(x)=(b-Ax)^T(b-Ax)}$.

Textbook Solution: $Q\bf{(x)=(b-Ax)^T(b-Ax)}\\\qquad \;= \bf{b^Tb-2x^TA^Tb+x^TA^TAx}.$

Hence, $\dfrac{\partial Q(\bf{x})}{\partial\bf{x}}=\bf{2A^Tb+2A^TAx}$

Thus, $\dfrac{\partial^2Q(\bf{x})}{\partial\bf{x}\partial\bf{x^T}}=2\bf{A^TA}.$

My Solution: $Q\bf{(x)=b^Tb-2x^TA^Tb+x^TA^TAx}$

Hence, $\dfrac{\partial Q(\bf{x})}{\partial\bf{x}}=\bf{-2A^Tb+A^TAx}$

Thus, $\dfrac{\partial^2Q(\bf{x})}{\partial\bf{x}\partial\bf{x^T}}=\bf{A^TA}$

Question: Did I made any mistake? And if not why is my answer not matching?